# Little trouble with inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I am having a little difficulty trying to solve a beginner proof in the topic of inner product spaces.

The statement says,

suppose $a_1,…,a_n \in \mathbb R$,

Prove that $(a_1+…+a_n)^{2}/n \le a_1^2+…+a_n^2$

I am thinking I definitely need to use the Cauchy shwarz inequality but there is  a few things I am unclear on. Is $(a_1+…+a_n)^{2}$= $\lt a_1+…+a_n,a_1…+a_n \gt $, and how else to approach. Any answers or help would be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to clarify one point, the (standard Euclidean) inner product of $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ with itself is the right side, $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + ... \ldots a_n^2$. I don't think the numerator of the left side is anything special with respect to inner products.

Comment: Ah I see, are you saying that I should first start with the RHS being equal to the inner product of (a1+..an) with itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac{(a_1 + \cdots + a_n)^2}{n} = \left( \frac{a_1}{\sqrt{n}} + \cdots + \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^2.
$$
Can you use Cauchy-Schwarz on this?

Comment: I think part of my issue is that whenever I have seen the cauchy inequality, it is in the form of (u,v) for example, like to distinct vectors but I am confused on if we have one here or what?

Comment: Can you express what I have written on the RHS as an inner product? Think of the definition of the Euclidean inner product.

Comment: Hm, could I write the RHS as the inner product with itself?

Comment: Very nice hint. +1

Comment: @LearningMath Think of $\;u=(a_1,...,a_n)\;,\;\;v=\left(\frac1{\sqrt n},...,\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)\;$ ...

Comment: Im still not exactly sure, is there any way you could elaborate on the solution? I appreciate the hints, but Im not sure if what I am saying is valid or not? Should I start with writing the RHS of the original equations as the inner product of the a's with themselves? and then the LHS and the inner product of u,v in the manner suggested by Timbuc?

Comment: @Learning : With the above notation, CSB inequality says that $$\langle u\,,\,v\rangle^2\le ||u||^2\cdot||v||^2$$ Now write this **exactly**

Comment: @Timbuc okay so if I do that I would get $(a_1+..+a_n/\sqrt{n})$ ^2 $\le (a_1^{2}+…+a_n^{2})(1/$\sqrt{n}$+..+1/$\sqrt{n}$)? But how does this help?

Comment: @LearningMath You're not taking the norm of $(1/\sqrt{n},\ldots,1/\sqrt{n})$ correctly (and you need to square it, not that it matters in this particular case)...

Comment: Oh should it just be (1/n+…+1/n)?

Comment: Yes...which is equal to?

Comment: (1/ $\sqrt{n}$+…+1/ $\sqrt{n}$)^${2}$?

Comment: No, that's completely off. $(a^2 + b^2) \neq (a+b)^2$. Stop doing algebra and think: *how many $1/n$'s are in that sum?*

Comment: n of them, so it becomes 1?

Comment: Yes...so now what do you have in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: @neuguy now I have $(a_1+..+a_n/ \sqrt{n})^{2} \le (a_1+..+a_n)^{2}$

Comment: Think about the hint I gave you at the start...and no, that's NOT what you have.

Comment: But is it valid to say $(a_1+..+a_n/ \sqrt{n})^{2} = (a_1+…+a_n)^{2}(1/\sqrt{n})^2$

Comment: Oops right I meant $ (a_1+…+a_n/ \sqrt{n})^2 \le (a_1^{2}+…+a_n^{2})$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21592/discussion-between-neuguy-and-learningmath).

Answer (score 1):

If we're using the form of Cauchy-Schwarz that says $\lvert\langle x, y\rangle\rvert^2 \leq \langle x, x \rangle \langle y, y\rangle$, we can expand this component-wise. Then we have

$$(x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + \ldots x_ny_n)^2 \leq (x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \ldots + x_n^2)(y_1^2 + y_2^2 + \ldots +y_n^2).$$

Your inequality looks like

$$\frac{(a_1 + a_2 + \ldots a_n)^2}{n} \leq (a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \ldots a_n^2).$$

If you multiply both sides by $n$, it seems likely that you want to use $x = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$. What would be a  suitable $y$?

Comment: wouldn't y be the same as x? or would we want to include the n component on every entry of x?

Comment: The $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \ldots + a_n$ is $\langle x, x \rangle$. So the $y$ you're looking for (if you multiply both sides by $n$) needs to have $\langle y, y \rangle = n$, and it needs to be such that $\langle x, y \rangle = a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n$. My answer/hints are the same as the rest in that both of our 2nd vectors "point in the same direction." I just didn't normalize it so that $\lvert \lvert y \rvert \rvert = 1$.